# XSD validation error: usage of xs:any in xs:element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

In my XML schema I have following definition:

```
<xs:element name="otherResultData">
    <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:element>
```

This will give the validation error:

> The content of 'otherResultData' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: any.

Is there a way to define it as: "there can be any content here, but if the types can be found in this XSD, then they are valid"?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
<xs:element name="otherResultData">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```